# (beginner) dynamically map a resizeable background image css

Tags: html, css, background, mapping

i am desperately trying to map a "resizeable" background image.
this is the homepage wich i'm trying to get mapped so visitors will be able to choose between the two options "events" & "elektriciteit".
when you resize your browser window the background will to and i need the mappings to resize with the background. Thanks!

[Homepage](http://users.telenet.be/KimBerger/Index.html)

css:

```
html {background: url('background.jpg')no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;
```

html:

```
<link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the size of the background image to change when you resize the browser to any dimension. If so, you can set the width and height of the background to be 100%.

```
background-size: 100%, 100%;
```

Comment: yes but i already got that, i want the two options "events" & "elektriciteit" to be clickable so i can hyperlink them to a next page :-)